# jQuery: Trigger self-unbinding event before it would get executed normally

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

I have a button, which gets binded a click listener named "The first", that binds another click listener named "The second" to it, when the condition is true. If the first is executed and the condition is true, I want to make sure, that if the second listener is already binded to the button, it is triggered first before proceeding and binding it again.

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdqh1ksk/)

My problem is, that the second listener invokes twice after only one click, what shouldn't be possible, because the second listener should unbind itself from the button. The console outputs

```
The first listener.
The second listener.
The second listener.
```

instead of

```
The first listener.
The second listener.
```

How can I achieve, that the second listener only gets invoked once and unbinds itself after that?

Comment: Can you create a demo? Very simple issue by the way, but needs a demo to verify it.

Comment: I agree with @dfsq. your obscured code is creating more confusion so worth creating a small demo on jsfiddle

Comment: @dfsq That's true. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdqh1ksk/) . The new popover shouldn't disappear after it's created, when the condition is still true. At the moment it's only displayed every second click.

Comment: @MihirSolanki I've done that, see post or comment above this one.

Comment: @elterPro not sure but could you please check whether this is what you want - [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/L0wtgpnm/)

Comment: @MihirSolanki No it isn't, because the popover still gets destroyed, even if the condition is true. And that is, because the second listener doesn't destroy itself when I trigger it manually and so it is still going to execute on that click.

Comment: @elterPro have a look at this one [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/fdqh1ksk/6/)